# RoR undefined method 'to_datetime' depending on order of helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I am experiencing a very odd problem; I get this error

> undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass"

when `render 'modal'` is before `render 'post'` in `show.html.erb`, but not if it is after:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Indlæg af <%= @user.first_name %></h2>
</div>

<% if current_user == @user %>
    <%= render 'modal' %>
<% end %>
<%= render 'post' %>
```

I have attached the views in the gist underneath:

Gist: https://gist.github.com/czepluch/8166841

It makes no sense to me that this error occurs depending on the order the renders are placed in. So I would really like to know why the order of the rendering of the helpers matter?

Comment: Rather than link to a gist, please go ahead and post the relevant code here. We won't need all of it, just the parts which illustrate your problem.

Comment: And that includes the code from your controller, not just the views

Comment: Also, a bit of the stacktrace would be helpful to determine which of your gems this is occurring in. I think I have tracked this down but want to make sure.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 0):

Please add code to the question so it is saved with the answers here.  I suspect it has to do with the fact that your form has this:

```
simple_form_for([@user, @user.posts.build]
```

That means a new post is built that has no attributes, which could cause a nil error later on.  reverse the order, and this isn't built until after the other code has run.   The only thing I can see at first glance that is related to datetime would be:

```
time_ago_in_words(p.created_at)
```

If created_at is nil, because of an empty post, that could generate an error.

Play with the form declaration, you may be able to do

```
simple_form_for([@user, :post])
```

or something like that to get a form for a new post without actually attaching an empty object to the @user object.